# C equivalent of C++ delete[] (char *)

Tags: c++, c, free, delete-operator

What is the C equivalent of C++

```
delete[] (char *) foo->bar;
```

Edit: I'm converting some C++ code to ANSI C. And it had:

```
typedef struct keyvalue
{
  char *key;
  void *value;
  struct keyvalue *next;
} keyvalue_rec;

// ...

  for (
    ptr = this->_properties->next, last = this->_properties;
    ptr!=NULL;
    last = ptr, ptr = ptr->next)
  {
    delete[] last->key;
    delete[] (char *) last->value;
    delete last;
  }
```

Would this do it for **C**?

```
free(last->key);
free(last->value);
free(last)
```

Comment: If you allocated memory with malloc, then you need to use free.

Comment: re @Sam's comment: Same goes for calloc which you may have used if bar is indeed an array.

Comment: Why would you use a cast there?

Comment: Well you'd need to cast if bar is actually a `void*` (pretend it's legacy C code or something).

Comment: @Mark: ouch, casting to char* because it's void*?  How should the compiler now which destructors to call if you don't know what array your pointing to?

Comment: @stefaanv Yeah that's the scariness: You're relying on the fact that in this context `bar` is ALWAYS a `char*`, which is just a bad idea. All I was trying to do is suggesting one possible case where the cast would be required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C, you don't have `new`; you just have `malloc()`; to free memory obtained by a call to `malloc()`, `free()` is called.

That said, why would you cast a pointer to `(char*)` before passing it to `delete`?  That's almost certainly wrong:  the pointer passed to `delete` must be of the same type as created with `new` (or, if it has class type, then of a base class with a virtual destructor).

Comment: I'm converting some C++ code to ANSI C. And it had

for (ptr=this->_properties->next, last=this->_properties;
ptr!=NULL;
last=ptr, ptr=ptr->next) {
delete[] last->key;
delete[] (char *) last->value;
delete last;
  }

where 

typedef struct keyvalue {

  char *key;
  void *value;

  struct keyvalue *next;

} keyvalue_rec;


But plain

free(last->key);
free(last->value);
free(last);

would do it for C?

Comment: @inquam:  Do those pointers point to memory allocated using `malloc()`?  If so, then use `free()` to free them.

Answer (score 2):

Just plain 'ol `free()`. C makes no distinction between arrays and individual variables.

Answer (score 0):

The C equivalent to `delete` and `delete[]` is just `free` ?

Comment: I guess you mean `delete` and `delete[]`, otherwise we would be speaking different C and C++ dialects :).

Comment: @Pieter: Yes that's what I meant :)

Answer (score 0):

Same as for non-arrays.

```
free(foo->bar)
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent would be:

free(foo->bar);

since you were typecasting it to (char *) which means whatever the actual type of 'bar' was there would have been no destructor called as a result of the cast.